# Changing a Link by pressing a button using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I am trying to create code, so that when you press a button, the link will change.
Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="body">
<div class="mainbody">
<p id="para"></p>
<h1>Here is my next Javascript Example</h1><br />
<p id="link1"><a href="index.html" title="Portfolio main" target="_blank">Portfolio Main</a></p>
<input type="button" value="Change Link" id="bttn2" onClick="changeLink();" />    
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript code:

```
// JavaScript Document
function changeLink()
    {
    document.getElementById("link1").innerHTML="Paramore";
    document.getElementById("link1").href="http://www.paramore.com";
    document.getElementById("link1").target="_blank";
    }
```

My problem is, when I press the button, the link changes, but the word that appears 'Paramore' isn't actually a link.

Comment: you're targeting the p, not the link. put the id on the link and immediately close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[1] id="link1" should be in the anchor tag instead of the paragraph tag

[2] Use the .setAttribute method for javascript DOM objects

```
obj = document.getElementById("link1");
obj.setAttribute("href","http://www.paramore.com");
obj.setAttribute("target","_blank");
```

Comment: Please cache your your node-references (rather than querying the DOM every time).

Answer (score 1):

> the link changes, but the word that appears 'Paramore' isn't actually a link.

That's because you've replaced the link with just the static text `Paramore`, because by setting the text of the paragraph, you've wiped out the link.

If you move the `id="link1"` attribute from the `p` element to the `a` element, that will sort it.

Alternately, do this:

```
var anchor = document.getElementById("link1").getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
anchor.innerHTML="Paramore";
anchor.href="http://www.paramore.com";
anchor.target="_blank";
```

But I have to say, changing an anchor on click is pretty dodgy.

Comment: +1 for your last sentence alone (though, obviously, the *rest* is entirely valid also!)

Answer (score 0):

the ID needs to be on the `<a>` element. Not the `<p>` element. Try this:

```
<div id="body">
<div class="mainbody">
<p id="para"></p>
<h1>Here is my next Javascript Example</h1><br />
<p ><a id="link1" href="index.html" title="Portfolio main" target="_blank">Portfolio Main</a></p>
<input type="button" value="Change Link" id="bttn2" onClick="changeLink();" />    
</div>
```

The same way it was done here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_elmnt_innerhtml

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("link1") will get you the **paragraph <p>** element, what you want is the **anchor <a>** element. Might I suggest you put the attribute *id="link1"* on your  instead?